# Ordering AOP Aspect and Advisor

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have an aop advisor and an aspect referencing the same pointcut, like so:

```
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="mypointcut" advice-ref="retryInterceptor" order="20"/>

    <aop:aspect ref="myAspect" order="1">

    <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="mypointcut" method="afterThrowingAdvice" throwing="e" />

    </aop:aspect>
```

Both my retryInterceptor and my afterThrowingAdvice listen for a hibernate DataException at mypointcut, but no matter what I put for my ordering, my advisor always runs first.

How do I ensure my after-throwing aspect will run before my interceptor?

Comment: I am not a Spring user, but do both your aspect and advisor implement the `@Ordered` interface like in [the aspect example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering#aop-ataspectj-example) and the [advisor example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering#aop-schema-example)? BTW, advisors are an outdated concept from Spring 1.2. Why don't you just refactor the advisor into an actual aspect?